# in winapi __stdcall on x86, what register is 2nd paramter in?

Tags: assembly, x86, stdcall

in winapi __stdcall on x86, what register is the 2nd parameter stored in?
(ECX?)  - also, any idea where i can find some documentation on this?

Comment: I think the parameters are stored on the stack, not the registers for stdcall.

Comment: Documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/zxk0tw93.aspx. The parameters are stored on the stack (referenced by `[ESP]` or `[EBP]`). Note: the calling convention for Win64 differs substantially!

Comment: @rkhb oh on the stack, thanks! could you add that as an answer? for personal note though, if i want to access 2nd parameter, it's DWORD PTR SS:[esp-4]   ?

Comment: or -4*parameter maybe

Comment: I know it, I saw it in the documentation and I can work with it, but I can't prove it to my satisfactory - so let it be as a comment. Access to the parameter depends on the "prologue" and the current position (inside the caller or inside the callee). Show code ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For stdcall the parameters are stored on the stack and it is the callee that removes them afterwards.
The first parameter will be at [esp+4]
The second parameter at [esp+8]
Every push made by the function/callee will make these offsets to ESP larger.

Using a default prologue of `push ebp` and `mov ebp,esp` the first parameter will be at [ebp+8] and the second parameter at [ebp+12].